# Separate Port forwarding with two public interface

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding

I have two public interfaces on machine #1
eth0 with IP 1.2.3.4 gateway 1.2.1.1
eth1 with IP 5.6.7.8 gateway 5.6.1.1

and have machine #2 with IP 9.8.7.6

I set port forwarding with iptables on machine #1

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 9.8.7.6:443
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERAD
```

when I send request to 1.2.3.4:443, I get response
but when I send request to  5.6.7.8:443 I don't get any response

when I trace packets, all forwarded packets received by 9.8.7.6 come from 1.2.3.4 and response goes back to it.

How can I separate outgoing packets and receive response when send request to 5.6.7.8:443?

Comment: It would help if you provided these results (please obfuscate them adequately): `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; ip rule`, as well as `iptables-save -c`.